# How to calculate the 3D vector perpendicular to a polygon surface in a specific direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, game-development

I'm creating an asteroid mining game in Unity 3D, where "down" is the center of the planet you are on (So I am mostly using local rotations when dealing with vectors).  I have a working physics-based character controller, but it has problems dealing with slopes. This is because when I add a force to the character, currently it pushes along the player's forward vector (see picture).  What I want to do is calculate the vector that is parallel to this terrain surface, but in the direction that the player is facing (so that the player can move up the slope).

[image: ms paint drawing]

I originally thought that i could just find the vector perpendicular to the normal, but then how do I know which direction it will be in.  Also complicating matters is the fact that the player could be oriented in any way in relation to the global x, y, and z.

Either way, I have the surface normals of the terrain, I have all of the player's directional vectors, but I just can't figure out how to put them all together. I can upload code or screenshots of the editor if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added a Rigidbody and played around with the Rigidbody properties?

Comment: Yeah, I already am using a rigidbody-based approach. Nico solved the problem for me though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way is to factor out the component of the forward vector that is parallel to the surface normal:

[image: Illustration]

```
fp = f - dot(f, n) * n
```

See [vector rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection_2).

This formulation will also make `fp` shorter the steeper the slope is. If you don't want that, you can re-scale `fp` afterwards to have the same length as `f`.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much, now I know another insanely useful vector function

Comment: Also, thank you for editing the post to include the picture inline.  Can you tell me how you did that so I can do it right next time?

Comment: You are very welcome. You can add images with the image button of the editor. I believe you need at least 10 reputation to post images, which you have by now. If you don't have enough reputation, the image probably shows up as a simple link.